# Using Android Admob sdk I receive same banner all the time

Tags: android, admob

Using Android Admob sdk I receive same banner all the time. On different devices banner is different.
Traces show request for ad and response.
No error or warnings about admob.
Code from my program:

```
OnCreate()
{
....
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    m_adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Here is request sent from admob sdk to server:

10-12 13:09:28.828: I/Ads(3865): adRequestUrlHtml: AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":10,"session_id":"5459438313201923230","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"19","slotname":"a14faa4a66469eb","u_w":320,"msid":"com.datecs.bgmaps","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.1.0","toar":0,"mv":"8014017.com.android.vending","isu":"CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"25.android.com.datecs.bgmaps","hl":"bg","extras":{"_norefresh":"t","gw":1,"mad_hac":"1"},"u_h":533,"carrier":"28401","ptime":362288,"u_audio":3});

I saw "_norefresh" in request url, but I control banners from admob site - refresh rate 45sek. So tis souldn't be a problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I stop internet - my ads continue to show on screen. sdk repeats last banners cached somewhere in device. On 20-30 ad request I receive once: 'No ads to serve for you' or some like this. So Admob repeat last banners when there is no connection or no new ads from google.
False alarm and spent 2 days to fight nonexistent problem.